# android temporarily use setEnabled(false)

Tags: android

I am animating an ImageView so that when you click the image the animation occurs (then later it resets) but my problem is that if you click again where the image sat originally - the animation starts from the beginning right away with out finishing (it just resets and starts again.

so I tried using

```
   setEnabled(false)
```

which works great, the animation continues on its path up perturbed by any random clicking, now the only problem is getting the ImageView enabled again - at about the same time as the animation stops

here's what i have

```
 stopImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mpButtonClick.start();
            stopImage.setEnabled(false);

            TranslateAnimation  anim = new TranslateAnimation(0f,250 + Math.round(Math.random() * (-700)),0f,-300f);

               anim.setDuration(4200);
               anim.setRepeatCount(0);

           stopImage.startAnimation(anim);
```

now is there an easy way i can call setEnabled(true) after a some time has passed?

Comment: Can you not tell when your animation is over? May we see the code for your animation?

Comment: @Safetylegs You can edit your original question to fix errors like "up perturbed"

Answer (score 2):

You could try using an `AnimationListener` and then calling `setEnabled(true)` from `onAnimationEnd()`.

Something like this:

```
stopImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        mpButtonClick.start();

        TranslateAnimation  anim = new TranslateAnimation(0f,250 + Math.round(Math.random() * (-700)),0f,-300f);

        anim.setDuration(4200);
        anim.setRepeatCount(0);
        anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
            {
                stopImage.setEnabled(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
            {
                stopImage.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        stopImage.startAnimation(anim);
    }
}
```

Here's the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) for `AnimationListeners`.

Comment: looks good and totally makes sense... but on the line anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() it's getting an error like "the method setAnimationListener(animation.animationlistener) in the type animation is not applicable for the arguments... and then errors on the start repeat and end (probably related?)

Comment: Try using 'Animation.AnimationListener' instead of just AnimationListener, hopefully that works.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad I could help!  If this solves your problem, could you mark this answer as "Accepted"? That way, when users have similar problems in the future, they can quickly see that this solution works.